# How to implement API call to send data from Tizen Watch App to Companion App(iOS)

Tags: android, ios, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

I'm working on an application where i'm planning to get the Heart Rate Vitals from Samsung Gear Active 2 and 3 watches by developing a Tizen Watch App(Web Applicatoin) which keep sending the vitals to the Android app either using Peer to Peer connection or Web API. So far i have a clear idea on how to get this feature done in Android, but for iOS App i want the same vitals to be read from samsung gear.

But it is not possible with Tizen Watch app communicating with iOS App.

So I'm thinking to Implement a RESTFull API Services in the watch application, which i should able to implement those same services in iOS to read the vitals data.

If the above approach is achievable, i have few questions related to the same.

1. Is it possible to have RESTFul API Services implementation in Tizen Watch App (Web Application).
2. Does Tizen has its own networking layer to implement RESTFul API Services?
3. Is there any other way of sending Tizen Watch App data to iOS Application ?

Any help/suggesstions is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you found anyway to do this?

Comment: @nadim Yes, we have developed a tizen watch app, which collects the heart rate from the sensor and save it locally and share the same data via BT of the watch. iOS mobile app can connect to the BT of Samsung watch and receive the data using BLE Protocol.